# Searching product by clicking search button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I want to search for my product to display on my browser by clicking the search button.

I can search products by Postman API nicely. But, I have no idea to display data by clicking the search button.

product.js

```js
router.get("/find/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json(product);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//GET ALL PRODUCTS
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const qNew = req.query.new;
  const qCategory = req.query.category;
  try {
    let products;

    if (qNew) {
      products = await Product.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(1);
    } else if (qCategory) {
      products = await Product.find({
        categories: {
          $in: [qCategory],
        },
      });
    } else {
      products = await Product.find();
    }

    res.status(200).json(products);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Navbar.js

```js
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <Button>Search</Button>
   );
  };
  
  export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use Axios to make a request from your react application.

To do this you need to install and require Axios into your react application.

This code will allow you to make a request to your express application:

```js
async function getProduct(productID) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`/find/${productID}`);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

This is going to only work when you know what the ID of the product you're searching is. If you have another endpoint on your server to search for a product via name you can change the endpoint accordingly. [Here](https://axios-http.com/docs/example) are the Axios docs.

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my actual question is how to i wite the code like `onclick` event in the button and hooks as well in Navbar.js @Kermit